# Crossplatform and free time tracking app with server

Tags: time-management

Please recommend time-tracking software.
Requirements:

- zero interaction from user to track time: a simple demon what monitors "computer is used/unused" is ok
- crossplatfrom: Linux, MacOs, Windows
- client-server architecture: daemon sends data to server, server writes it to DB.
- self-hosted
- client identification
- free

I want to obtain data like this:

- Computer1 was used from 11:00:01 until 12:03:15, from 12:19:03 until 14:18:15
- Computer2 was used 9:06:31-16:05:15

I don't care much about gui/etc. All I want is data on one server and zero efforts from user.

Comment: the best option I found so far is ActivityWatch: https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch